# An NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSLog(@"%@",context);
        // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"%@",context);

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {enter code here
        NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }

    // Remove device from table view
    [self.devices removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


   }
}
```

the error is   An NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863724/an-nsmanagedobjectcontext-cannot-delete-objects-in-other-contexts)

Answer (score 1):

The instance of the NSManagedObjectContext that you are using to fetch NSManagedObject is different than the current one.

Check this also: [An NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863724/an-nsmanagedobjectcontext-cannot-delete-objects-in-other-contexts)

Comment: you have self.devices. it is array of core data objects. at some method you fetch this array with using NSManagedObjectContext...but in the code above you use another instance of NSManagedObjectContext when delete. It feels like you do a big mistake with using your own array of core data objects through methods, it is not safe. better to use NSFetchedResultsController to be in sync.

Comment: sir can i send you my app plz solve the issue plz sir

Comment: yep. i will try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You must have fetched the objects in the array associated with `self.devices` with a different NSManagedObjectContext than the one that is returned by calling `[self managedObjectContext]`.  The object you are trying to delete cannot be changed or operated using a different context, which is why you are getting the error.

What you can try to do, if you want to delete that object, is pull it out and then delete/change the object like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context;

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSLog(@"%@",context);
        // Delete object from database
        MyObject *object = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        context = object.managedObjectContext;
        [context deleteObject:object]
        NSLog(@"%@",context);

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {enter code here
        NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }

    // Remove device from table view
    [self.devices removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


   }
}
```

This will work in your situation, but what you should really do to make your code much easier to work with is use an NSFetchedResultsController.  Here are some useful links about how to use it:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/index.html