# Deleting an object in a different context

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, concurrency, thread-safety

I have an issue with subscribing and unsubscribing in my app, where the user when clicking on subscribe will send a server call and download data from the server and store in db. At the same time, if the user clicks on unsubscribe button, I have to delete the same data in db. I am getting an error of trying to access an object from different contexts.

I wanna know whether there is a way to do in concurrency where I can delete the object in a private context[Unsubscribing process] and then save the changes once the subscribing process is finished.

I am unable to delete the object this way, Can someone suggest me where I am going wrong?

```
    func deleteStreamEntityInPrivateContext(_ id: Int){
    privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateContext?.parent = CoreDataService.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext

    privateContext?.perform {
        if let stream = self.getStreamEntity(id){
            let managedObjectContext = CoreDataService.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext
            let streamID = managedObjectContext.object(with: stream.objectID)
            debugPrint(streamID, stream.id)
            self.privateContext?.delete((self.privateContext?.object(with: stream.objectID))!)
        }
    }

}

func saveStreamEntityInPrivateContext(){
    if let privateContext = privateContext{
        if privateContext.hasChanges{
            do{
                try privateContext.save()
                if CoreDataService.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext.hasChanges{
                    CoreDataService.sharedInstance.saveContext()
                }
            }catch{
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show relevant code (remove code) and the exact error. Also set tag for the language used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863724/an-nsmanagedobjectcontext-cannot-delete-objects-in-other-contexts)

Comment: The link that you gave was the one I followed to clear the error, but the problem persists. My subscription is still in the process of storing data to db, but when the user clicks on unsubscribe at this point, I am deleting the object in db. I have a solution, where I cannot allow the user to click on unsubscribe until the subscribe process is complete, but I wanna know whether is there any other way to do this?